# How to set preset eq in android?

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I want to develop a preset equalizer(not graphical)  and set like a classical,jazz,normal,rock(these are represented in spinner). Can anbody help me regarding this.

Comment: Hey Sony..howz u ? i am also searching for same doing..have u found any solution regarding set equaliser in android as jaaz , pop, normal ..?pls suggest me if u get any thanks

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7564400/874752

Answer (score 6):

i got the solution for it,Code is shown below here:

```
 Equalizer mEqualizer;

 short m=mEqualizer.getNumberOfPresets();

 music_styles = new String[m];

 for(int k=0; k <m ; k++) 

 music_styles[k]=mEqualizer.getPresetName((short) k);



  // it gives 10 presets by equalizer engine.(normal,classical,rock etc.) By setting through the following code


mEqualizer.usePreset((short)x); where x is preset x<10
```